# listener on tab click or activation not working properly / extjs4

Tags: c#, tabs, refresh, listener, extjs4

I am developing an application with extjs4 and c#, it is based on the [browser-layout example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html).
I have a menu on the left side, where you can click each item of that menu. On the right side I have all of my tabs.

The event listener I'm using on the tabs works when I click on the tab, but doesn't work *after* the first time I click on it from the left menu.

To be clearer, when I first load my application, I have to select an item from left menu, it then shows my tab with tab1 activated. Everything works well, except it doesn't work when I select another item then go back to my tab.

This is my listener:

```
  listeners: { activate: function () {                                  
                               alert('tab1');                                  
                          }
             },
```

Here is the code called when clicking the menu:

```
menuPanel.getSelectionModel().on('select', function (selModel, record) {
    if (record.get('leaf')) {
        Ext.getCmp('content-panel').layout.setActiveItem(record.getId() + '-panel');
        Ext.getCmp('cardTabs').setActiveTab(0);
}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

I added a listener to my tabpanel

```
 listeners: { tabchange: function () {
                    //refresh 
                    switch (this.getActiveTab().id) {
                        case 'myId1': myFunction();
                        .........
                        }
                },
```

Answer (score 2):

once check the below url:

http://jsfiddle.net/6NK7n/6/

```
var sample1 = {
    id : 'example1',
    border : false,
    title : 'sample1'
};
var sample2 = {
    id : 'example2',
    border : false,
    title : 'sample2'
};
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
    title : 'example',
    width : 300,
    height : 300,
    draggable : false,
    plain : true,
    id : 'examplepanel',
    activeTab : 0,
    border : true,
    renderTo : document.body,
    items : [sample1,sample2],
    listeners : {
        beforetabchange : function(tab,newTab,currentTab){
            if(newTab.getId() == 'example1'){
                alert('sample1 tab is selected');
            }else if(newTab.getId() == 'example2'){
                alert('sample2 tab is selected');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ok thanks it worked now, but the same way as activate did, i still dont get an alert when i click on the left menu not on the tab :( any idea about this?

Comment: its the [browser-layout example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) the only modified code is the called on menu click i already shared it in my question. js for  [main sccript](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/layout-browser/layouts/basic.js) , [layout script](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.js) . let me know if u need something else. (i dont know how else i can share my code)

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `beforetabchange`  instead of `activate` listener.Try the following one:

```
listeners : {
beforetabchange : function(tab, newTab, currentTab){
if(newTab != null){
if(newTab.getId()=='tab1'){
alert('tab1');
}
}
}
}
```

Like above you can write tha listeners for each tab that you wish to execute.

Comment: it doesnt work :(  i dont get any alert message anywhere, even if i tried without the if condition, even with tabpanel id or tab id !